# WebDeploy only if package is newer than current deployment

Tags: webdeploy

I am using WebDeploy packages to update UAT and Production environments.  Is it possible to run the deployment process such that it will only actually deploy if the package is an update to the currently deployed application?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my observations it appear that this is in fact the default behaviour.